# conditional match in Power BI (date and time custom condition)

Tags: excel, powerbi

I need a help to solve one issue. I work on a project to find one value in an another array with conditions. I have two sales data tables one from Company web ("Transaction date and time" and "amount") and another from bank ("Transaction date and time" and Amount")
I need to find that which transactions from Company data are in transactions from bank data. I could do this with match function, but there is transaction time difference (approx. less than one minute) between Company data and Bank data.

My aim is to write a match function in Power BI or Excel like "in values" one condition for amount and one condition for "date and time" column, but as there is time difference, I have to write something  (like interval) that considers this condition.

Process is: in Company data first row amount is 10$ and function finds first 10$ in bank data and check date and time, if time is approximately same ( difference can be max 30 minutes) - matchede (can be written TRUE), if not next row and so on...

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please post data as text. Consider using [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)